# Can Precision + Recall be used to compare two feature extraction logics for the same classification model algorithm?

Tags: model, precision, feature-extraction

Context. We have two algorithms to perform Feature Extraction (FE) with creating target variables. Each is used as input to the same (say Logistic regression or XGBoost) model. The task is to compare those two FE algorithms. The same dataset is used for both FE algorithms.
I decided to create two models by doing training for each FE algorithms. Then for each trained model I calculate Precision and Recall. I would like to use those Precision and Recall metrics to compare FE algorithms.
Is this approach correct?